# Python indexing of values in a list

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to calculate an average of hours worked/day during a week. What I managed is below:

```
listing_hours = []
hours_sum = 0
num = 0
days = input("How many working days are there: ")
number_days = float(days)
amount_days = int(days)
for array_of_days in range(amount_days):
    num = num + 1
    hours = input("Provide " + str(num) + ". hours worked on this day: ")
    number_hours = float(hours)
    hours_sum = float(hours_sum) + number_hours
    listing_hours.append(hours)
average_hours_day = float(hours_sum)/float(days)
hours_decimal = []
for item in listing_hours:
    hours_decimal.append(float(item))
print("The hours input was:", str(hours_decimal[0]) + "h,", str(hours_decimal[1]) + "h,",             
str(hours_decimal[2]) + "h,", str(hours_decimal[3]) + "h,", str(hours_decimal[4]) + "h, 
total was", hours_sum, "hours.")
print("Average working day length was", str(round(average_hours_day,2)), end="h.")
```

It seems to be working, however, I was wondering how to approach the display of inputs and total hours (in penultimate line in the code above). As you can see I have a placeholder in the form of str(hours_decimal[XXX]. This of course won't do, as the number of days in the first input can be any value. How do I capture the index associated with the certain day?

The desired format of the display is something as follows: "The hours input was: (hours worked in the first day, say 8)h, 6.5h, 11.0h, etc., total was 43.75 hours." Currently I am just placing the order number from the list, but it only works, if I know how many days there were in the input.

Comment: Why do you first convert the number of days to a float and then int? Why not just `amount_days = int(days)`?

Comment: This isn't C, you don't need to convert numbers to `float` before dividing them.

Comment: @Barmar This isn't Python 2, you don't need to convert numbers to `float` before dividing them... oh wait, Python 2.7.(16?) is still the default on many systems!

Comment: @Barmar, for average. Suppose I worked 8h 30min, thats 8,5h. I want to be able to input that.

Comment: @Arthur I'm not talking about hours, I'm talking about days: `amount_days = int(days)`

Comment: So you take user input `str`, store it in listing_hours. You change it to `float` for sum and throw it away. Then you take the `str` from listing_hours, change it `float` (*again*) and put it in hours_decimal. The take it from hours_decimal and change it *back to* `str`.

Comment: @Barmar, oh that one. The line number_days = float(days) is not used anymore anywhere. I was trying to get the average and run into some issues before. I forgot to delete the line. Thanks for the solution, by the way. I think I will still try to do it through list, since that is what I am trying to practice now.

Comment: @Faboor, this required some backtracking. Yes, indeed all that was going on. I was getting type error, that why all the floats and placeholder variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generator and `join()`

```
print("The hours input was:", ", ".join(f"{h}h" for h in hours_decimal))
```

Comment: Make it a generator instead of a list and you'll have my upvote ;)

Comment: OK, generated it

Answer (score 0):

Using generators and `statistics.mean` makes this quite a bit simpler:

```
from statistics import mean

hours = [
    float(input(f"Provide {num+1}. hours worked on this day: "))
    for num in range(int(input("How many working days are there: ")))
]

print(f"The hours input were: {', '.join(f'{h}h' for h in hours)}")
print(f"Average working day length was {mean(hours)}h.")
```

```
How many working days are there: 5
Provide 1. hours worked on this day: 8
Provide 2. hours worked on this day: 6
Provide 3. hours worked on this day: 12
Provide 4. hours worked on this day: 5
Provide 5. hours worked on this day: 6
The hours input were: 8.0h, 6.0h, 12.0h, 5.0h, 6.0h
Average working day length was 7.4h.
```

Comment: pretty, but I'm not fan of having the hours input *on a line before* the days input, because the order differs from the actual experienced/intended order of events.